# Cisco SFP for single-strand single mode connection over 10km

Tags: cisco, fiber, sfp

Is it possible using only Cisco equipment to link two sites approximately 15km apart using only one single mode fiber strand.

Comment: What about using regular dual-strand optics with a circulator? (see http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=373)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. All of the single-strand fiber SFP's from Cisco that I know of are limited to 10km.

Answer (score -1):

The older SFPs are limited to 10KM, however see the list below for longer distance.

- 10KM Single Mode Fiber - GLC-LH-SMD
- 40KM Single Mode Fiber - GLC-EX-SMD
- 70 - 100KM Single Mode Fiber - GLC-ZX-SMD

Part details can be found [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/interfaces_modules/transceiver_modules/installation/note/78_15160.html)

Comment: These are single mode transceivers, but they are not single strand.

Comment: ahh missed the fine point, i take it back in that case.